# Blender 2.9+ Mirror Flip a Texture

Tags: texturing, uv, mirror

So, i've done Mirror Texture Boundaries in other programs, but i can't quite figure out how to do it in blender, i know it should be possible.
To be more specific, i'm looking to do something like this. Lots of nintendo models use mirrored textures like this and stuff. It should be possible right? [image: what i mean]

Comment: If your object is mirrored with the Mirror modifier, you can either keep the modifier or apply it, the UVs will be mirrored, therefore the texture will appear mirrored on the object

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should tell us what you want to do as an end result?

you can mirror a texture with the help of shading nodes like this:

[image]

so the "trick" is to just use negative scale values for a coordinate...